# How to pass an argument or parameter in storybook decorator during translation in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I am trying to figure out that Is there anyway to pass argument in decorator in order to translate page in React Storybook. I have sample code below if you could help me out to pass an argument in decorator.

```
const stories: Meta = {
  title: '/TestComponent',
  component: TestComponent,
  decorators: [
    storyWithTranslation()
  ],
  argTypes: {
     test: {
      options: ['us', 'jp', 'de'],
      control: { type: 'select' },
      defaultValue: 'us',
    },
  },
};

type Story = StoryObj<
  typeof TestComponent & {
    test: string;
  }
>;

export const Default: Story = {
  render: ({ test }) => { // this is working fine
    return (
      <TestComponent test={test} />
    );
  },
  args: {
    test: 'en-us',
  },
  decorators: [({test}) => storyWithTranslation(test)] // wanted to achieve something like this. 
};
```

Is there anyway we can pass the argument in the above ?